# How to change url dynamically after packaging Metro apps?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, package, winjs

Hi I have created a package for my metro application.Here while developing my app I have given a Url static,But I need to change Url dynamically whenever my requirement changes.So that what should I do?Can anyone help me.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use web service or Azure cloud storage which gives you URL, so when your URL get changed you have to change in web service/Azure only.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirements are changing, then you might be releasing a new version of your application anyways, so it might make sense to just update your app package manually each time the URL changes and re-release it. This is definitely the simplest solution if your URL is going to change infrequently. You would also need to handle deprecating the old URL in this instance or at least gracefully handling when the old URL is shut down so that users who have not upgraded to your latest version still don't have a horrid experience.

If that is not a viable option, then it gets a bit messier from here on. Really the only way to change the stored URL would be to have some sort of secondary service or authority on what the current URL is. The app would then do one of the following (or a combination):

1. Query the URL authority for the current URL *before* making any requests.
2. Attempt to make the request to the current stored URL, if it fails, query the URL authority for the new URL and store that URL.